# problem with react-router-dom.production.min.js

Tags: react-router-dom

I'm creating a React project where I'm using react-router-dom@6.2.2. I'm trying to host my project on the internet, but it gives the following error after building the project and running it. I start by building the project with webpack that generates a file from the html template. This error was very strange to me and I'm almost certain that the error is due to something in the mimified file. Because this error does not occur in development.[image]

this is the production webpack file

```
const { DefinePlugin } = require('webpack')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin')
const { merge } = require('webpack-merge')
const common = require('./webpack.common')

module.exports = merge(common, {
  mode: 'production',
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.ts(x?)$/,
      loader: 'ts-loader',
      exclude: /node_modules/
    }, {
      test: /\.scss$/,
      use: [{
        loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader
      }, {
        loader: 'css-loader',
        options: {
          modules: true
        }
      }, {
        loader: 'sass-loader'
      }]
    }]
  },
  externals: {
    react: 'React',
    axios: 'axios',
    'react-dom': 'ReactDOM',
    'react-router-dom': 'ReactRouterDOM'
  },
  plugins: [
    new DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.API_URL': JSON.stringify('https://fordevs.herokuapp.com/api')
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './template.prod.html'
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: 'main-bundle-[contenthash].css'
    })
  ]
})
```

This is the `template.prod.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
  <title>4Dev - Enquetes para programadores</title>
</head>

<body>
  <main id="main"></main>
  <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
  <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
  <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/axios@0.24.0/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
  <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-router-dom@6.2.2/umd/react-router-dom.production.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I think you might also need `history@5` and `react-router@6`. Just basing this from [HTML Script Tags](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/main/docs/getting-started/installation.md#html-script-tags).

Comment: still having the same problem my friend

Comment: I managed to change it by making your recommendation and something else. I will answer my question to help others. However, thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this problem by adding the mimic script from history@5 and react-router@6 as suggested by friend [Drew Reese](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8690857/drew-reese). However, I had to change the file loading sequence as well. My `template.prod.html` file ended up like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
  <title>4Dev - Enquetes para programadores</title>
</head>

<body>
  <main id="main"></main>
  <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
  <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/history@5/umd/history.development.js"></script>
  <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
  <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-router@6/umd/react-router.development.js"></script>
  <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-router-dom@6.2.2/umd/react-router-dom.production.min.js"></script>
  <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/axios@0.24.0/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```